# Simple ASM Bootloader to iso

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, boot, bootloader

I created a simple asm hello world x86 bootloader, I'd like to embed it into an iso file, I was following this http://wiki.osdev.org/Bootable_El-Torito_CD_with_GRUB_Legacy but this embed my kernel inside grub, not just a bootloader

I didn't want to rely on floppy images once again, how can I create a ISO file for my 512 bytes bootloader? (replacing an existing iso file bootloader isn't exactly a solution I like, I'd rather do something else)

Comment: Really, why not just make a bootable floppy image and make a bootable ISO image out of it with the mkisofs tool (or equivalent)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest answer I can think of is [this](http://wiki.osdev.org/El-Torito).